# creating sqlite3 db cache in the form of dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I have class with functions to populate, update and access records in sqlite3 db. Earlier records were stored in dictionary which was giving performance issues for adding high # of records say 100k which I changed to use sqlite3. Now challenge I am facing is keeping its caller code keep working.

Earlier there was `self.resources` as dictionary with records which is now removed. So now I want to provide records from sqlite3 db in the form of `self.resources`

sqlite3 db has multiple tables with columns(id, value1, value2) and callers want to access tablenames using `self.resources` or ids from perticular table as `self.resources['tablename'].keys()`

So my question is,

how can I achieve this without modifying class. By writing decorator or some other way to provide records from db depending on call e.g. `self.resources` then provide only table names or if `self.resources['tablename'].keys()` then provides values from `id` column for perticular table.